# How can I automatically track PayPal donations and display it on my site?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to automatically track PayPal donations and display the current donation amount in my site.

So, How can I do it?

Should I use PHP?

Do you know tutorials for it?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=paypal+and+php&hl=en&prmd=v&source=univ&tbs=vid:1&tbo=u&ei=nDKRTLapLMeOjAeo07XzDA&sa=X&oi=video_result_group&ct=title&resnum=5&ved=0CC4QqwQwBA Try them videos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might take a look at the Instant Payment Notification system https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf .  It would allow you to setup a receiver page that would be notified of each paypal payment.